# How to check if hash includes a word

Tags: ruby

I want to check if a hash includes a word retrieved from `gets.chomp`. I tried like this:

```
words = {}
while true
  puts "What do you want to do?"
  puts "1) Learn a word to Baby."
  puts "2) Check how many words Baby has learn."
  action = gets.chomp
  if action == "1"
    puts "Write a word that you want to learn to Baby"
    word = gets.chomp.capitalize
```

This is the problem:

```
if action == "1" && words[word].empty?
  words[word] = Time.now
  puts "With a succes you have learn {Word} to baby."
  if action == "1" && words[word].any?
    puts "This word is already learned by the baby."
```

How can I check if `word` (this can have +1 value because it's while) is already in a hash and if it is then user can't learn that word to baby.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168482/discussion-on-question-by-dion-how-to-check-if-hash-include-a-word-ruby).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use *words.include?(word)* for array or *words.key?(word)* for hash